# redirecTo() method in laravel not working

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I have been trying to redirect a user after login, there are two links that should be redirected to when a certain condition is fulfilled.

```
protected function redirectTo(){

    $userRole = User::findOrFail(Auth::id());
    // dd($userRole->roles);
    if($userRole->roles == 'admin'){

        return 'admin/controlpanel';
    }

    elseif ($userRole->roles == 'participant') {

        return 'student/profile';
    }
}
```

I created this function to redirect but it still redirect to '/home'. Then I read  over here and on git that I also had to the modify RedirectIfAuthenticated model in the middleware, I did this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;


class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return self::redirectTo();
    }

    return $next($request);
}

protected function redirectTo(){

    $userRole = User::findOrFail(Auth::id());
    if($userRole->roles == 'admin'){

        return 'admin/controlpanel';
    }

    if ($userRole->roles == 'participant') {

        return 'student/profile';
    }
}
}
```

but is still keeps giving me this error in my previous question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846921/laravel-5-5-session-issues-addcookietoresponse)

I reverted to my previous git commit, then coded step by step till I discovered it was coming from the middleware I modified...

Comment: Where's the top redirectTo used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `redirect` helper like this: `return redirect('admin/controlpanel');`